# Netfilter string module example usage

Tags: c, linux-kernel, netfilter

Can anybody point me to some examples in using the xt_string module with netfilter or provide a example.
What I am trying to do is to write netfilter module that will drop packets that contain a certain string in the skb->data field.

I initially tried simply `strnstr(skb->data, "mystring", strlen("mystring"))` but this seem to be incorrect approach to this problem (and it does not seem to be working as i dont see any packets being dropped).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you mean using iptables string match in user-space, here is one example:

```
iptables -I INPUT 1 -p tcp --dport 80 -m string --string "domain.com" --algo kmp -j DROP
```

Or if you mean in kernel space, you can use textsearch API which provides KMP/BM/FSM algorithms, the following example is from kernel source lib/textsearch.c:

```
int pos;
struct ts_config *conf;
struct ts_state state;
const char *pattern = "chicken";
const char *example = "We dance the funky chicken";
conf = textsearch_prepare("kmp", pattern, strlen(pattern),
                             GFP_KERNEL, TS_AUTOLOAD);
if (IS_ERR(conf)) {
    err = PTR_ERR(conf);
    goto errout;
}
pos = textsearch_find_continuous(conf, &state, example, strlen(example));
if (pos != UINT_MAX)
    panic("Oh my god, dancing chickens at %d\n", pos);
textsearch_destroy(conf);
```

Comment: Yes, you are right, I do mean kernel space. This piece of code looks like something I need. Gonna try it out. Thanks Cong Wang

Answer (score 3):

what you are looking for may be this one, "skb_find_text".
It uses the infra in linux mentioned by @Cong Wang.
You can also find some examples in the kernel codes.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score -1):

here after a source code of netfilter. it's a module to drop received ICMP ECHO

you can use this code to help you to develop your module. You have just to get data from skb and then check it.

```
#define __KERNEL__
#define MODULE
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/slab.h>
#include <linux/list.h>
#include <linux/netfilter_ipv4.h>
#include <linux/ip.h>
#include <linux/icmp.h>
#include <linux/netdevice.h>
#include <linux/netfilter.h>

#include <linux/skbuff.h>
#include <linux/string.h>
#include <linux/inet.h>

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");


static struct nf_hook_ops netfilter_ops_in;/* IP PRE ROUTING */
static struct nf_hook_ops netfilter_ops_out; /* NF_IP_POST_ROUTING */
struct sk_buff *sock_buff;
struct iphdr *ip_header;
struct net_device *dev;
char *in_face = "eth0";
char *out_face = "eth1";

void log_ip(int sadd,int dadd)
{
    int b1,b2,b3,b4;
    b1 = 255 & sadd;
    b2 = (0xff00 & sadd) >> 8;
    b3 = (0xff0000 & sadd) >> 16;
    b4 = (0xff000000 &sadd) >>24;

    printk("SrcIP: %d.%d.%d.%d",b1,b2,b3,b4);

    b1 = 255 & dadd;
    b2 = (0xff00 & dadd) >> 8;
    b3 = (0xff0000 & dadd) >> 16;
    b4 = (0xff000000 & dadd) >>24;

    printk("  DstIP: %d.%d.%d.%d",b1,b2,b3,b4);
}

unsigned int main_hook(unsigned int hooknum,
                        const struct sk_buff *skb,
                        const struct net_device *in,
                        const struct net_device *out,
                        int(*okfn)(struct sk_buff*))
{
    struct icmphdr* icmp;
    sock_buff = skb_copy(skb,GFP_ATOMIC);
    ip_header = (struct iphdr*)(sock_buff->network_header);
    //ip_header = ip_hdr(sock_buff);

    icmp = (struct icmphdr*) ((char*)ip_header + sizeof(struct iphdr));
    //icmp = icmp_hdr(skb); /* do not return a good value in all cases*/
    log_ip(ip_header->saddr,ip_header->daddr);
    printk("  Dev:%s\n",sock_buff->dev);

    if (icmp->type == ICMP_ECHO)
    {
        printk("ICMP ECHO received and droped\n");
        return NF_DROP;
    }
    return NF_ACCEPT;
}

int init_module(void)
{
    netfilter_ops_in.hook       = main_hook;
    netfilter_ops_in.pf         = PF_INET;
    netfilter_ops_in.hooknum    = NF_INET_PRE_ROUTING; /*NF_INET_PRE_ROUTING;*/
    netfilter_ops_in.priority   = NF_IP_PRI_FIRST;

    nf_register_hook(&netfilter_ops_in);


    printk(KERN_INFO "sw: init_module() called\n");
    return 0;
}

void cleanup_module(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "sw: cleanup_module() called\n");
    nf_unregister_hook(&netfilter_ops_in);
    //nf_unregister_hook(&netfilter_ops_out);
    printk(KERN_INFO "sw: hook unregisted, quit called\n");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but I know how to do all that. My only issue is with finding a string within the skb->data field.