# IPv4 packet-payload processing (cuda,opencl)- netfilter?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, ipv4, netfilter

I´m trying to write a custom kernel-module for packet matching (e.g. string matching).

I know this can be done using the --string option in iptables, but I want to learn to do it from scratch for the puropose of expanding my knowledge in C and kernel-development.

What would be good starting point ?

My idea was to match a packet in kernel-space (maybe with NF-Hooks), send it to userspace for processing (using CUDA or OpenCL and netlink sockets) and then send back the result (drop,accept,...) to the kernel.

Is this at all possible or does this have do be done all within the kernel ? Will the kernel wait
for a packet to be processed in userspace at all?

I know I would have to dig in deep, but curiosity kills me ;-) !

Thanks for any tips !

Kind regards

Comment: It can be done and [has been done](http://an.kaist.ac.kr/~sangjin/pub/sigcomm2010_packetshader.pdf)

Comment: I´ve since been looking at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13401096/netfilter-string-module-example-usage 
It does actually not look too difficult ! Thanks for that paper !